# How to solve Maven error: A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am trying to create a maven report in Eclipse using a Mojo. I only have only 2 files for the project, and I followed the directions pretty closely for building a Maven Report; however, I keep getting the issue my class that should be injected is not being injected.

Upon looking further, it keeps saying that AbstractMavenReport cannnot be found.

Here is the error message:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.simplemavenreport.maven.SimpleMavenReport
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.simplemavenreport.maven.SimpleMavenReport not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:124)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:712)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.findClassInternal (ClassRealm.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:432)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:124)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (AccessController.java:712)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.findClassInternal (ClassRealm.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:432)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:124)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
```

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenreport</groupId>
  <artifactId>simplemavenreport</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
   
  <name>simplemavenreport</name>
  <description>3rd Time</description>
  
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <doxiaVersion>2.0.0-M7</doxiaVersion>
        <doxiaSitetoolsVersion>2.0.0-M11</doxiaSitetoolsVersion>
    </properties>
 
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Doxia API and Doxia Sitetools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-sink-api</artifactId>
            <version>${doxiaVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>${doxiaSitetoolsVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- reporting API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-reporting-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-M9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-reporting-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-M7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- plugin API and plugin-tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shared-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.9.0</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>    
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>simplereport</goalPrefix>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-descriptor</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generated-helpmojo</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  
</project>
```

here is the only java file that I have in the program

```
package com.simplemavenreport.maven;


import java.util.Locale;
 
import org.apache.maven.doxia.sink.Sink;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.ResolutionScope;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport;
import org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException;
 
/**
 * Builds an simple report page as an example.
 *
 * <p>
 * This example show how easy it is to build your own reporting plugin
 * (or, for that matter, your own reporting Mojo)
 *
 */
@Mojo(
       name = "simple",
       defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.SITE,
       requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME,
       requiresProject = true,
       threadSafe = true
     )
public class SimpleMavenReport extends AbstractMavenReport {
 
    public String getOutputName() {
        // This report will generate simple-report.html when invoked in a project with `mvn site`
        return "simple-report";
    }
 
    public String getName(Locale locale) {
        // Name of the report when listed in the project-reports.html page of a project
        return "Simple Report";
    }
 
    public String getDescription(Locale locale) {
        // Description of the report when listed in the project-reports.html page of a project
        return "This simple report is a very simple report that does nothing but "
        + "shows off Maven's wonderful reporting capabilities.";
    }
 
    /**
     * Practical reference to the Maven project
     */
    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true )
    private MavenProject project;
 
    @Override
    protected void executeReport(Locale locale) throws MavenReportException {
 
        // Get the logger
 
        // Get the Maven Doxia Sink, which will be used to generate the
        // various elements of the document
        Sink mainSink = this.getSink();
        if (mainSink == null) {
            throw new MavenReportException("Could not get the Doxia sink");
        }
 
        // Page title
        mainSink.head();
        mainSink.title();
        mainSink.text("Simple Report for " + project.getName() + " " + project.getVersion());
        mainSink.title_();
        mainSink.head_();
 
        mainSink.body();
 
        // Heading 1
        mainSink.section1();
        mainSink.sectionTitle1();
        mainSink.text("Simple Report for " + project.getName() + " " + project.getVersion());
        mainSink.sectionTitle1_();
 
        // Content
        mainSink.paragraph();
        mainSink.text("This page provides simple information, like its location: ");
        mainSink.text(project.getBasedir().getAbsolutePath());
        mainSink.paragraph_();
 
        // Close
        mainSink.section1_();
        mainSink.body_();
 
    }
 
}
```

On the command line, I run mvn clean install, which works fine. but when I go to run the goal, I get this error message. I run the goal with the following command:

mvn com.mavenreport:simplemavenreport:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:simple

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks

I have tried changing the versions, and I have tried changing the dependencies but nothing seems to work. I was expecting a report to be generated, but it was not.

I also deleted the entire maven repository on the ./m2 repository to no avail.

Comment: The dependency to maven-install-plugin, maven-plugin-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin is wrong. Remove them first. Second take a look here: https://github.com/apache/maven-jxr/tree/master/maven-jxr-plugin (into pom.xml) for the dependencies...